# 'Animation<double>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Listenable'

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am following a tutorial on how to animate a page view and show progress as one transitions from one page to another. Here is the question and answer [Progress Bar Animation In PageView in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261725/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-animation-in-pageview-in-flutter)

After writing the code I get an error that `The argument type 'Animation<double>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Listenable'` and `Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Animation<double>'`.

This is the code where I get the error

```
class AnimatedProgressBar extends AnimatedWidget {
  AnimatedProgressBar({Key? key, Animation<double>? animation})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<double> animation = listenable;
    return Container(
      height: 6.0,
      width: animation.value,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
    );
  }
}
```

The specific lines with errors are

`AnimatedProgressBar({Key? key, Animation<double>? animation}) : super(key: key, listenable: animation);`

and
`final Animation<double> animation = listenable;`

Answer (score 0):

The property `listenable` is non-nullable which means that you need to use the [null assertion operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator) `!` or cast your animation as a non-nullable `Listenable`.

Moreover you need to cast back your `listenable as Animation<double>` when assigning it:

```dart
class AnimatedProgressBar extends AnimatedWidget {
  AnimatedProgressBar({Key? key, Animation<double>? animation})
      : super(
          key: key,
          listenable: animation!, // or `animation as Listenable`
        );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final animation = listenable as Animation<double>;
    return Container(
      height: 6.0,
      width: animation.value,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
    );
  }
}
```

### Alternative

Instead of force casting your `animation` as a non-nullable you should make it required in your constructor so it cannot be null, then you wouldn't need the cast anymore:

```dart
class AnimatedProgressBar extends AnimatedWidget {
  const AnimatedProgressBar({
    Key? key,
    required Animation<double> animation, // Now required and cannot be null
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          listenable: animation, // No need to cast anymore
        );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final animation = listenable as Animation<double>; // Still need to cast here
    return Container(
      height: 6.0,
      width: animation.value,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
    );
  }
}
```